# Error: Map container is already initialized. Angular 14 / Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic4

I use Leaflet in my Ionic application, we also use Angular, after we updated the app to version 14 of Angular, the map started behaving strangely, when we open the map the screen goes white and this error message appears in the console:

```
ERROR Error: Map container is already initialized.
    at e._initContainer (node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet.js:5:38551)
    at e.initialize (node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet.js:5:27056)
    at new e (node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet.js:5:2667)
    at t.map (node_modules\leaflet\dist\leaflet.js:5:145971)
    at CheckinCheckoutComponent.createMap (checkin-checkout.component.ts:191:18)
    at Object.next (checkin-checkout.component.ts:84:16)
    at ConsumerObserver.next (Subscriber.js:91:33)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:60:26)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at innerFrom.js:61:28h
```

This is the TS:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, Input, OnChanges, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../../../environments/environment';
import { MarkerArray } from '../../../../core/models/map-box/marker-array';
declare let L;

@Component({
  selector: 'm-map-box',
  templateUrl: './map-box.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map-box.component.scss']
})
export class MapBoxComponent implements AfterViewInit , OnDestroy {
  @Input() markersArray?: MarkerArray[] = [];
  @Input() mapID: string = 'map';
  @Input() config? ={
    'height': '180px',
    'width': '100%',
    'z-index': 10
  };
  map: any;
  markers: any[];

  constructor() { }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.createMap();
    console.log(this.markersArray)
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.markersArray = [];
    if (this.map && this.map.remove) {
      this.map.off();
      this.map.remove();
      this.map.invalidateSize();
    }
  }

  createMap() {
    this.map = L.map(this.mapID).fitWorld();
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
      subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      accessToken: environment.Leaflet_Token
    }).addTo(this.map);
    const _markers = this.prepareMarkers();
    this.setMarkers(_markers);
 
  }

  setMarkers(markers: any[]){
    if(this.markersArray.length > 0){
      var group = L.featureGroup(markers).addTo(this.map);
      this.map.fitBounds(group.getBounds());
    }
  }

  prepareMarkers(){
    const _markers: any[] = []
    this.markersArray.map((marker)=>{
      let Icon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: marker.icon.iconUrl,
        iconSize: marker.icon.iconSize,
        iconAnchor: marker.icon.iconAnchor,
        popupAnchor: marker.icon.popupAnchor// point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
      });

     // L.marker([marker.latitude, marker.longitude]).addTo(this.map);
      _markers.push(L.marker([marker.latitude, marker.longitude], { icon: Icon }).bindPopup(marker.popup));
    })
    return _markers;
  }
}
```

This is the html:

```
<div [ngStyle]="config" [id]="mapID"></div>
```

The map is used in a few different components.

In some blog it says to insert this line:
this.map.invalidateSize();

But that didn't help me, what the hell am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the CheckinCheckoutComponent, it seems the exception is thrown there

Comment: Hi, really the problem was in another component, thanks for the light, with the help of another post I managed to solve my problem, I will post an answer to help someone else who comes across the same.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of another post, I managed to solve my problem, here's the part of the code that was giving trouble:

```
  private createMap() {
    this.map = L.map('map2').fitWorld();
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
      attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
      subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
      accessToken: environment.Leaflet_Token
    }).addTo(this.map);
    this.map.locate({ setView: false });
    this.getLocatizationPDV();
  }
```

I added this line, and everything worked:

```
    if (this.map != undefined) this.map.remove();

private createMap() {
if (this.map != undefined) this.map.remove();
        this.map = L.map('map2').fitWorld();
        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
          attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
          subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
          id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
          accessToken: environment.Leaflet_Token
        }).addTo(this.map);
        this.map.locate({ setView: false });
        this.getLocatizationPDV();
      }
```

It was thanks to this post that I found the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58592199/21684458

Thanks so much :)